# Why does substitution into a sympy derivative only partly work

Tags: sympy, derivative

I am trying to use symbolic derivatives and the chain rule in sympy, prior to substituting explicit functions.
For example, I just tried this in https://www.sympy.org/en/shell.html, expecting to get the same result for both print lines:

```
from sympy import diff, Function, Symbol

c = Symbol('c')

a = Function('a')(c)

b = Function('b')(c)

V = a*b*c

print(diff(V,c))

V = Function('V')

print((diff(V(a,b,c),c).subs(V(a,b,c), a*b*c)).doit())

c*a(c)*Derivative(b(c), c) + c*b(c)*Derivative(a(c), c) + a(c)*b(c)
c*a(c)*Derivative(b(c), c) + c*b(c)*Derivative(a(c), c) + Subs(Derivative(V(a(c), b(c), _xi_3), _xi_3), _xi_3, c)
```

In the last line, the substitution was not done for the last term. Is this a bug or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last print statement shows that SymPy's `subs` is unable to perform the requested substitution inside the `Sub` class (yeah, it's a bit confusing). That's because `subs` is looking for `V(a(c), b(c), c)`, whereas inside the `Sub` class the function has been automatically replaced by `V(a(c), b(c), _xi_3)`.

So, we need something more powerful to perform the substitution. We can use the `replace` method and wild symbols, which are used for pattern matching operations, like the one we are going to do now:

```py
from sympy import *
c = Symbol('c')
a = Function('a')(c)
b = Function('b')(c)
V = Function('V')
# create a wild symbol: in its basic form, it will match everything
w = Wild("w")
print(V(a,b,c).diff(c).replace(V(a,b,w), a*b*w).doit())
# out: c*a(c)*Derivative(b(c), c) + c*b(c)*Derivative(a(c), c) + a(c)*b(c)
```

Let's dive into the last command:

- `V(a,b,c).diff(c)` does the symbolic differentiation. It introduced the `Sub` class which replaced `V(a, b, c)` with `V(a, b, _xi_3)`.
- We use the `replace` method to perform the substitution: we are asking it to search for patterns of the form `V(a, b, w)` where `w` can be anything. We want to replace this pattern with `a * b * w`. So, in this case SymPy will find two matches:

  1. `V(a, b, c)` which will be replaced by `a * b * c`.
  2. `V(a, b, _xi_3)` which will be replaced by `a * b * _xi_3`.
- Finally, apply the `doit` method to perform the computation.

Comment: This is a bug: `diff(V(a,b,c),c)` should not give an expression with dummy variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just wanted to report it as a bug, but now I think the problem is that sympy is missing a way to express partial vs. total derivatives.  `Derivative(V(a, b, c), c)` refers to the total derivative of `V(a,b,c)` with respect to `c`, whereas the last term of the solution has to be a partial derivative. Apparently, taking the derivative wrt a dummy variable is interpreted as a partial derivative: Compare `display(Derivative(V(a,b,c), c))` with `display(Derivative(V(a,b,w), w)` where `w` is a wild card.

Comment: This is now https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23990