# Substituting undefined function in symbolic expression

Tags: function, undefined, sympy, substitution

In an expression depending on an unknown function f of r**2, I would like to replace the function f by some actual function and display the result but I cannot find a way to do it. Here's an example:

```
r = symbols('r', real= True)
phi = r * Function('phi')(r**2)
dphi = phi.diff(r)
print(dphi)
```

At this stage I get:

```
2*r**2*Subs(Derivative(phi(_xi_1), _xi_1), _xi_1, r**2) + phi(r**2)
```

Now let's assume I would like to evaluate dphi when phi(y) = y.

This should give me:

```
2*r**2 + r**2 = 3*r**3
```

How do I make the actual substitution of phi in dphi to obtain the desired result ?

@Davide_sd This is an example that works as I expect (but for a function of r alone):

```
r = symbols('r', real= True)
phi = Function('phi')(r)
om = r * phi
dom = om.diff(r)
dom.subs(phi, sin(r)).doit()

output: r * cos(r) +sin(r)
```

But I would like to have for example (does not work):

```
r = symbols('r', real= True)
phi = Function('phi')(r**2)
om = r * phi
dom = om.diff(r)
dom.subs(phi, sin(r)).doit()

output: 2*r**2*Subs(Derivative(phi(_xi_1), _xi_1), _xi_1, r**2) + phi(r**2)
```

Instead I would like to get:

```
2*r**2*cos(r**2) + sin(2*r**2)
```

Thanks in advance for any help,

Regards,
Bernard.

Comment: Please, can you show how you defined `y` and how you tried to perform the substitution `phi(y) = y`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want `phi(y) = y` this is the `Id` function; replacement can be done as:

```py
>>> from sympy import Id
>>> dphi.subs(Function('phi'), Id).doit()  # where dphi is as given at the start
3*r**2
```

In your example for `dom` it is not clear what function mapping you want since you use `phi` for the expression `Function('phi')(r**2)` and for the function `Function('phi')`. If you mean the same as in the first example -- something like `phi(r) = sin(r)` then you would just replace `Function('phi')` with `sin`.

Another way to approach this is by using `replace` to find occurrences of the function of interest and replace them with desired value, regardless of argument.

```py
>>> p = Function('phi')
>>> (1+p(x)).replace(lambda x:x.func==p, lambda x:x.args[0]**3)
x**3 + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Replacing Function('phi') with sin does indeed work for this example. I looked up the documentation but could not find a way to replace phi with r->r**3. In that case I would like the output to be 7*r**6. Do you know a way to do this ? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! your proposal provides exactly what I need. After finding on stack overflow another way of using 'replace', I summarise both ways below...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above answer and another usage of `replace` that I discovered here ([Why does substitution into a sympy derivative only partly work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73426255/why-does-substitution-into-a-sympy-derivative-only-partly-work)), here is a summary of two solutions that do exactly what I need:

```
>>> r = symbols('r', real= True)
>>> phi = Function('phi')
>>> om = r * phi(r**2)
>>> dom = om.diff(r)

# Solution 1
>>> dom.replace(lambda x: x.func == phi, lambda x: x.args[0]**3).doit()
7*r**6

# Solution 2
>>> y = Wild("y")
>>> dom.replace(phi(y), y**3).doit()
7*r**6
```